# Emscripten compiling Python error: Linking globals named 'hypot': symbol multiply defined

Tags: python, linker, emscripten

I am trying to build Python with emscripten and link it to my main program, but during the linking stage im getting:

`error: Linking globals named 'hypot': symbol multiply defined!`

which seems to be saying that there are multiple definitions of the global function `hypot`, I have `grep`ped hypot and only found one definition in pymath.c.

How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was emscripten was defining hypot when it provides the C standard library through emsdk. So the solution is to go into pyconfig.h and to `#define HAVE_HYPOT 1`.

Comment: also copysign needs `#define HAVE_COPYSIGN 1`.